# Not recognizing the variable neither the else statement

Tags: php

If is working only if the statement is false. when it's right it doesnt do anything.

I first tried with if - else , but my code was never entering the else statement. Then , as you can see i tried with a flag but the same thing is happening.

```php
if (isset($_POST['upload'])){

       $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
       $allowed = array ('kml','xml');
       $ext = pathinfo($filename ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
       if(!(in_array($ext,$allowed))){
           echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Error, Not a kml File");</script>';
       }
        else {

           echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("This,is a kml file");</script>';
       }
}
```

I expect that if i upload the right kml file , i want to echo that is right.

Comment: There is no else statement in your example?

Comment: Try echoing the $ext variable to see what's inside it.

Comment: But , in that case shouldnt be all the time false and echoing that is not kml file? Now , when its true , its doenst do anything

Comment: Yeah, ignore that, pathinfo doesn't actually care after all. Perhaps show us theoutput  of `var_dump($ext)`.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "when it's right it doesn't do anything"? You get a white screen? No echo? Checked error logs? Have you checked for an upload error?

Comment: all  of the code you wrote it's ok but I think your $filename doesn't have a good format

Comment: @Jonnix , it should echoing that the kml is right, but its not doing that. there arent error on logs or on upload.

Comment: @Jonnix C:\wamp64\www\Web\AfterLogin.php:13:string 'txt' (length=3) when its not a kml file. When it is , its not printing any path!

Comment: Which is line 13 in the code provided?

Answer (score 0):

Else statement is missing in your condition, Please do this way -

```
if (isset($_POST['upload'])){
       //$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
       $fileMimeType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
       // Check the mime type of your xml & kml file 
       $allowed = array ('text/xml','application/xml'); 
       //$ext = pathinfo($filename ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
       if(!(in_array($fileMimeType ,$allowed))){
           echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Error, Not a kml File");</script>';
       }
       else {
           echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("This,is a kml file");</script>';
       }
}
```

Comment: its not working , i did it that way and my code is never entering else statement

Comment: @GiwrgosTerezakis Updated the script, can you please try it

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['upload'])){
       $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
       $allowed = array ('kml','xml');
       $ext = pathinfo($filename ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
       if(in_array($ext,$allowed)){
           echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("This,is a kml file");</script>';
       }
       else {
           echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Error, Not a kml File");</script>';
       }
}
```

Try this

Comment: Again , its working only if the statement is false. Entering in else and echoing that its not a Kml file. When it is true , it doesnt echoing anything!